# How to get plain text from kendoEditor?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-editor

How to get only text from kendoEditor without style?

When I use `$("#id").data("kendoEditor").value()` it is returning value with style. But I want to get only text without the style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following snippet, which will just fetch Text within a DOM Element:

```
function getClick(e) {
    try {
        var text = $('#editor').getKendoEditor().value()
        var strippedText = text.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
        alert(strippedText);
    }
    catch (e) { }
}
```

Bind it with an HTML Button:

```
<button class="k-button" id="btnPreviewContent" onclick="getClick()">PreviewEditor Content</button>
```

Comment: No. I am getting like "My Text<span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"></span>". But I want only "My Text".

Comment: Check the updated post which contains a stripping Regex